# Find the CGPoint of a specific character in NSString/UILabel within the superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, cgpoint

Let's say I have a UILabel and the text is "Hello World". If I want to find the CGPoint value of the 'W' so that I can create a duplicate label with just a 'W' right on top of the old 'W', how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level you can calculate the size of the text up to the letter.

```
UILabel *label = ... // label with "Hello World"
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : label.font };
CGSize size = [@"Hello " sizeWithAttributes:attrs];

CGPoint newOrigin = label.frame.origin;
newOrigin.x += size.width;
```

At this point `newOrigin` should represent the original needs for the new label containing the `"W"`.

Create the new label with the same font and height as the original label. Use `newOrigin` as the new label's origin.

The code makes several assumptions:

1. `label` is set for left alignment
2. `label` is properly sized for the font (not too tall, not too short, not too narrow - resulting in a smaller font)

With a bit more work, those assumptions can be removed.